# How many edits automatically turn my answer into a Community Wiki answer?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I thought I read about this several years ago but can't seem to find it back (possibly a lack of searching skills).

I remember that if you edited a question too many (10+?) times, it was turned into a Community Wiki question automatically, and something similar applies to an answer. I also remember that there was a difference between self-edits and edits from others. I believe one of the reasons behind this was to prevent self-promoting your answers or questions by making many minor edits, to get it higher in the queue.

Does this limitation still exist and if it does, what are those limits?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this limit has been removed, but I'll have to go look for the reference.

Comment: @ChrisF, I could of course try to edit my question here up to, say, 20 times every 5 minutes, and if it turns into a community-wiki it's QED.

Comment: @Abel: if you do, the moderators are notified and we'll come looking to see what shenanigans you are up to.

Comment: @martijn, lol, sure, I didn't know it was auto-flagged, thanks!

Comment: Related – [How many edits to question for it to become community wiki?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327205/95735)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Answers are no longer automatically converted to Community Wiki, however many times you edit them. See [Can we disable automatic community wiki conversion for answer edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits)

Instead, posts that have been edited more than 10 times by their author are automatically flagged for moderator attention. We'll then take a look if the edits were material, or were instead being used to needlessly bump the post to the front page.

We can then either dismiss the flag (edits were substantial), leave a comment asking for the edits to be more substantial going forth, or send a message with a friendly warning if there were indications the edits were being made to draw attention only.

Comment: Great, thanks. Your searching skills are better than mine. :)

Comment: @Abel: well, I did post an answer on that Meta.SE discussion proposing the very change that was eventually made. Searching consisted of going to my Meta.SE profile and searching for *Community Wiki*, then pick that answer. :-P

Comment: Any chance to get a feature, which lets us edit without bumping to front page? Many small edits are often easier. With such a feature we could do it without the suspicion that we only do it to gain attention. In the long run this might improve quality of posts.

Comment: @Greenflow: [Could we have the ability to mark a change as minor in questions or answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26483)

Comment: *sigh* should have guessed that this was discussed already. :-)