# How many edits to question for it to become community wiki?

Tags: support, edits, reputation, community-wiki

How many edits to question for it to become community wiki?

I've found posts about answers. Not about questions.

Comment: I think that's an obsolete rule.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, obsolete per [Stop using community wiki as a reputation denial mechanism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228940/165773): "we have removed all of the automatic triggers that convert a post to community wiki. Edits by the original author, edits by other people, and even volume of answers, all of these no longer cause a post to be automatically converted to community wiki..."

Comment: @gnat - That should probably just be the answer :)

Comment: @TravisJ [here you go](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327206/839601) (and there's more for it, I'll edit the answer to add one more funny detail)

Comment: (jokes on you, I upvoted your answer prior to your comment)

Comment: @TravisJ You didn't mention him in your comment so he won't get notified. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since April 2014 no amount of edits can trigger automatic wiki conversion. This was announced at MSE, in [Stop using community wiki as a reputation denial mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228940/165773):

> we have removed all of the automatic triggers that convert a post to community wiki. Edits by the original author, edits by other people, and even volume of answers, all of these no longer cause a post to be automatically converted to community wiki...

---

More than that, this approach applies retroactively as [recently explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279348/why-do-community-wiki-q-a-not-get-awarded-reputation#comment905161_279349) by Director of Community Development for the Stack Exchange Network (Robert Cartaino):

> <sup>**Note to Moderators:** If anyone requests removal of a forced Community Wiki setting, it should be removed without hesitation (unless the author set it for their own answer or other extenuating circumstances).</sup>

With regards to CW removal another thing worth keeping in mind is that when it happens [reputation is recalculated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327205/how-many-edits-to-question-for-it-to-become-community-wiki/327206?noredirect=1#comment363183_327206) as if the post was never a wiki and since June 2014 [recalculation effect becomes immediately visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233945/165773).

Comment: It's worth noting that the change you mention at the end just made the effect *immediate*. Reputation was always recalculated in that way, it just never happened until the user's account was scheduled for recalculation for other reasons.

Comment: thatnks @animuson I suspected that it works this way but haven't seen it explained (edited the answer to account for that)