# How much reputation is given per documentation post per day - convert to community wiki

Tags: discussion, documentation, reputation

Has anyone looked into specific numbers of how much reputation is being given out on documentation?  It's like a hyperinflation, crashing any meaning to reputation as a measure of trust.

If you take any top up-voted documentation, such as [this at 423 up-votes](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays/404/creating-and-initializing-arrays#t=201607251521068986403):

> [image]

Then, look to the **72 users** who've edited that post:

> [image]

This pool of users is now collectively reaping the benefit:

Unnamed user 1, now top 0.54% this month:

> [image]

Unnamed user 2, now top 0.63% this month:

> [image]

Another way of looking at this, from three other users:

[image]

How much reputation is this documentation example giving per day?  60,000+ reputation points?

While I understand documentation is different than Q&A, where more edits and encouraged to refine documentation posts, at a certain point you'd think these would convert to community wiki.

Comment: CW isn't meant as a tool to deny rep. If rep-denial is the intended effect here, it's better to fix it at the source - i.e. documentation itself.

Comment: Let's make Documentation not give out any points, the serious folks who want people to build tools correctly don't care for the rep but they care about their docs.

Comment: Or we could make documentation give some benefit, but reduce it comparatively.

Comment: This beta affects overall production reputation - too early for these awards.

Comment: Quit your day job for a couple of months....edit everything you can find...then 2 months later when rep is in 1/4 million range go on job hunt in careers

Comment: By that time, @charlie, employers will have surely caught on to the fact that Documentation has led to a massive reputation inflation for Stack Overflow users, making it even less valuable as a hiring metric. So much for the people who have put in lots of effort composing high-quality answers to difficult programming problems. It's back to proving our competence with FizzBuzz at interviews.

Comment: This is mine: [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/x8f8u.png). Yeah, some form of limiting needs to happen there.

Comment: Damn, 400+ already? C++ doesn't even have anything that hit 100 yet. Come on, C++ voters, get it together.

Comment: To be honest, the amount of upvotes on that particular examples is also excessive here. But this won't go to infinity. The first days there's a lot of upvotes, but they're repcapped. In a week or so, I don't believe this example gets upvoted more than 20 times a day… … Seriously, if you write a really, really great answer and it comes into hot network posts this may sometimes happen too, to you.

Comment: @bwoebi Its entirely possible to have "hands in the pie" of every one of the top 20 voted posts on doc. I don't think the repcapping for people who actively try it and game the system will stop anytime soon

Comment: @Magisch I agree, it'd probably cause a steady income of rep. perhaps after a certain number of rep you shouldn't receive +5 per upvote, but only +4..3..2..1 sometime. … But yes, if you have your hands on that many posts, you end up with a good 10k rep nevertheless after a while. But what do you want to do about that?

Comment: @Magisch Similarly it is quite unfair to the late-comers, most regulars already have upvoted and won't give you any +5 rep anymore... Definitely needs a rebalance, but we'll see.

Comment: @bwoebi I don't know. But it certainly isn't hard. I wasn't specifically trying for it and I got "hands in" 4 or 5 high traffic posts. Someone who is determined to try will suceed with many more, for sure.

Comment: @Magisch But honestly, I don't care too much. They will rebalance it, I'm sure. But it's not a too pressing issue. It's _just rep_.

Comment: Log in to SO, +5 (SE inbox, please dont fill up my cap)...buzz (from phone)...another **** notification (computer)...5 mins later...+5 (SE inbox, I JUST EMPTIED IT)...buzz (from phone)...another **** notification (really)...5 mins later...+5 (writing a userstyle to remove it from the SE toolbar)...buzz (my leg is gonna fall off)...another **** notification (turns on do not disturb)

Comment: "Hyperinflation is ended with drastic remedies, such as imposing the shock therapy of slashing government expenditures or altering the currency basis. ....Thus it is not surprising that there exist at least seven historical cases in which the good (foreign) money did fully drive out the use of the inflating currency. In the end the government had to legalize the former, for otherwise its revenues would have fallen to zero." from Wikipedia. What does that sound like to you?

Comment: @CodyGray "people who have put in lots of effort composing high-quality answers to difficult programming problems" You mean people who are lucky enough to have been on SO up to 2011 when getting rep was easy?

Comment: @Magisch congrats on 10k (ooops, too soon. I'll come back next week:P).

Comment: @Barry Wait... are there people who up-vote C++ stuff? I thought the vote counter was capped at 0 for C++ questions.

Comment: Since you posted this about +20 users edited more to get into the rep truck

Comment: I'm totally for cutting all rep RIGHT NOW until there is some consensus on how rep should be rewarded. Allowing this to go on doesn't help the inflation. What if in the end we decide to just scrap the rep? By that time, who knows the effects of the inflation.

Comment: See overview of proposals, how to change current system of reputation gain from Documentation at [Remove or Overhaul Reputation in Documentation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329528)

Comment: Docs rep is probably broken and needs much rework but whatever they will do, automatic conversion to community wiki is better to avoid. [They already tried that trick on Q&A](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327206/839601) and it ended in tears and they dropped that and now they even officially endorse retroactive reversals of past CW conversions, go figure. Automatic CW conversion is a dead end

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> Has anyone looked into specific numbers of how much reputation is being given out on documentation?

Yup. I'd wager a few of us probably have. So here's a quick breakdown - keep in mind, this is *really* new and we're still adjusting the fundamentals, so extrapolating from it is sketchy. In particular, I would expect link-vote rep to increase as time goes on. I've included non-Docs reputation figures where appropriate for a sense of scale, since big numbers can be kinda hard to interpret otherwise.

Note: [new documentation rep rules have just gone into effect!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334551/documentation-reputation-update-is-live) - the numbers below now reflect the current state of the world.

***What follows reflects reputation earned on docs and Q&A between July 21st and September 14th:***

- Net reputation earned via Docs since the start of the public beta: **424,721 points** (for comparison, **22,620,852** points were earned outside of docs during this time)
- Median rep earned by Docs participants who've earned rep since the start of the public beta: **6 points / user** (for comparison, **10 points / user** was the median earned outside of Docs in this time)
- Number of users who've earned reputation via Docs in public beta: **9,623** (**581,323** users earned reputation outside of docs during this time)
- Most reputation earned by a single user from Docs in public beta thus far: **3,868 points** (max earned by a single user outside of docs over the same period: **19,056 points**)
- Most reputation earned (by all users) for a single example in public beta: **36,025 points** (yup, that Array Initialization thing) (max rep for a single post: **5,804 points**, for our old friend the branch prediction answer)

And, a raw breakdown of all docs reputation earned or lost, by type:

```
Name                     Rep Change 
------------------------ ---------- 
Doc Rep Source Removed   -20398     
Example Unupvoted        -16486     
Doc Link Unupvoted       -80        
Doc Link Upvoted         15975      
Proposed Change Approved 53840      
Example Upvoted          391870
```

Oh, and here's a fun one: who is earning what portion of that reputation, grouped by the top privilege level attained on the site *before* the start of the docs beta:

```
# of Users Privilege level before docs beta % Docs Rep Earned % non-Docs Rep Earned 
---------- -------------------------------- ----------------- --------------------- 
3946401    new user / none                  4.02 %            5.65 %                
342213     Newbie                           0.62 %            1.02 %                
611330     VoteUpMod                        3.24 %            3.88 %                
283855     PostCommenting                   5.23 %            5.12 %                
312992     VoteDownMod                      27.94 %           25.33 %               
13286      EstablishedUser                  1.93 %            2.52 %                
17891      PostEditing                      8.20 %            5.72 %                
23226      CloseQuestion                    25.11 %           15.83 %               
3321       ModerationTools                  7.85 %            6.16 %                
7532       TrustedUser                      3.17 %            6.66 %                
3255       ViewSiteAnalytics                11.72 %           20.83 %
```

(% values may not add up to 100% because I've overlooked something important)

A histogram showing how many people are earning various ranges of reputation (most common value by far is **2 points**):

[image: a histogram with irregular bucket sizes]

And a histogram showing how many examples have generated various ranges of reputation for their editors:

[image: Another histogram with irregular bucket sizes]

Comment: Modal (rather than mean) single-user reputation would be valuable as well.

Comment: Yeah, maybe later @josh. Super-early numbers, mostly looking for big scary anomalies.

Comment: Just curious, are these numbers available in the SEDE or are they internal SO data? Thanks!

Comment: Not directly, @luweiqi - this is straight from the raw rep history that feeds everything else. Exposing the docs parts would probably be OK, but some of the rest is sensitive.

Comment: Would it be convenient to include `Most reputation earned by a single user` for the Top 5 instead of 1, thanks!

Comment: Ok, @josh - replaced avg with median (you can calculate avg from the rest of the data presented). Also added a table with breakdown by privilege level and fixed some inaccuracies (no doubt others remain; I'm tired.)

Comment: ...wait, you asked for mode, not median. Ugh. Going to bed.

Comment: Computing from these numbers, we also get a mean rep earned per rep-earning user of 51 for Docs, compared to 16 for Q/A.

Comment: @user2357112 Huh, almost like the data bears out that rep inflation everyone sees. Another metric: Doc rep was 14.5% of SO rep (329798 vs 2272898) but it has 4.5% of the users (6459 vs 141918)

Comment: wonder if you consider an option of rep recalc if it turns out that things are way off (like it happened in [March 2010](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42905/165773))

Comment: @gnat They already confirmed changes applied to documentation rep will all be retroactive so thats definitely going to happen

Comment: [Already happened once](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328703/addressing-documentation-repgateapocalypse), @gnat - will almost certainly happen again.

Comment: I see, thanks. In that case, idea of Docs rep being shared with that of SO doesn't look as scary. Though it might take a while to find the right balance

Comment: I believe it's also interesting to compare *royalty* rep: max rep for a user based on a single edit (Docs) vs. from a single answer (SO main).

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist some people would say that that is "capitalism in its finest", since a small group concentrates much of the revenues.

Comment: Went with a histogram instead, @josh - because I like histograms.

Comment: Where'd the 680 come from?

Comment: Your rep history over a (now arbitrary) period of time, @Mysticial

Comment: Oh. I was gonna say, that can't be in one day since I've never gotten that much in one day. And it definitely can't be for all time. If it was for the first X days of the post's life (where X is the time that docs has been in public beta), then it's missing a 5 from the accept. Okay, I'll shut up. Clearly I was overthinking this.

Comment: Time period for all numbers here is (time I updated the numbers - start of public docs beta), @Mysticial. That includes the Q&A numbers.

Comment: ooooooooooooohhhhhhhh. Why didn't I think of the obvious...

Comment: Before you get too invested in the idea of "rep inflation", @Two-BitAlchemist, consider that *average* rep per user has been falling for Q&A for some time now, and is currently at an all-time low. Here's a fun graph: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aFPnR.png

Comment: Probably interesting, but not very useful right now, @PM77-1; massively mismatched time periods. NOTHING in docs can compete with the all-time score for that sorted array answer (or heck, [even something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/178450)); if you wanna compare days, then you gotta pick your days.

Comment: @Shog9 Sorry but how does that help? The community's perception seems to be that rep is harder than ever to **earn** on Q&A but easy to get in larger quantities _undeservedly_ on Docs. This seems like one more piece of data perhaps bearing that out. What's my blindness here? What do you see that I don't?

Comment: Privilege thresholds haven't really changed in years, @two. Commenting still requires 50; full edit rights are still 2k. If earning those privileges is more difficult now than in, say, 2014 then we're dealing with a *deflationary* system. That really shouldn't surprise anyone. But it presents a challenge when introducing new sources of reputation, because you probably *don't* want to chase that trend; you want someone documenting, say, React to be earning roughly par with someone answering React questions, *not* someone still trying to post answers to, say,  PHP dups.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist When you have a highly skewed distribution of data, as is the case here, medians provide a more informative comparison, not means.

Comment: the _Docs_ vs _QA_ metrics are related to content created in the same time span?. Another indicator that IMO may be useful (but probably hard to calculate depending on your settings) is the _RepGenerated/UniqueVisitor_ ratio (eg; QA had 1 million unique visitors giving 2,272,898 rep, meaning 2.3 rep points by unique visitor)

Comment: Is there actually 54 users who got between 1k - 2k rep from Docs?

Comment: Sure looks like it, @luweiqi. IIRC, the max earned was 1200 when I ran this.

Comment: Wow, that's quite a lot - 1000 in just 1 week

Comment: Rep-cap is 200, so 5 days is the minimum to earn 1000, @luweiqi.

Comment: Not created, just earned @FelipePereira. Limiting it to "created + earned" would be interesting, but I'll have to think about how that would apply to Docs before I go that direction (for example, adding a link to an old docs example to an old answer becomes a new rep-source - so should that count?)

Comment: Yup, some users earned 200 everyday since the public beta

Comment: One thing not captured by these graphs is how strong the correlation is between rep earned and quality of contributions in docs versus q&a. The perception is definitely that it's weaker, and that undermines confidence in rep.

Comment: My goal here is to provide concrete data, @samgak. Ideally, that helps all of us identify the critical problems and frame solutions in a way that'll actually help. Folks have widely varying opinions on the quality of the examples being edited, the usefulness of the edits themselves, and the quality of equivalent answers in Q&A... And as you can see from this answer, the reputation being earned varies widely as well. How - or whether - those correlate is something you'll have to decide for yourself.

Comment: @Shog9 Why did the # of users who've contributed to Docs go down when you changed the numbers to include more date data?

Comment: Auto-recalcs most likely, @tylerh

Answer (score 152):

**Disclaimer:** Of course I am not implying that *everyone* currently involved in the Docs is only in it for the rep - that would be absurd.

---

It seems that SO central understands quite well (maybe too well) the values of gamification. Proof of that is the success of the Q&A SO. What SO Central does not seem to understand is what happens when you experiment too much with your currency.

And what the OP reports is exactly what happens when you merge the Q&A rep system (which has well-known downsides but, to a degree, still holds true to its meaning) and the Docs rep system which has flaws deeply nested in its concept and implementation. What we have here is failure to gamify (aka how not to solve potential participation issues).

*(Addressing SO Central)*:
If you fear that participation will be low then **progressively** convey your intentions to a larger but still qualified userbase.
Do not use the Q&A rep as bait. If you do this (well, you did) 2 things are more or less bound to happen:

- First, you attract *en-masse* a **certain** type of users to Docs (viz rep-whores), while leaving other well-meaning potential Docs users/contributors  disheartened.
- Second, you undermine the single most important motive for the Q&A section: a rep system that can be trusted; enough so, as to be used as an (albeit rough) index of personal programming skills. And this will backfire on you. Maybe not now, but in the long run when all the fuss about docs settles down and users ponder on what their reputation means after all.

Maybe what SO Central thought was that after the initial big-whoop influx of low quality content, the more "serious" part of the community would take over and clean the mess. Really? Hand out rep like there's no tomorrow and then expect *who* exactly to handle the chore? People who care about the docs? But they did not need this kind of rep awards to get involved. And now, instead of having them in the first place create the backbone of the Docs, and make it easier for other users to add quality content upon it, we see the reverse phenomenon: Less qualified users creating the backbone and caring users trying to clean up the mess.

Not to mention that the mere fact that you gain rep for every example upvote is **preposterous**. And still getting rep even when your contributions are edited out is **absurd**. And still getting rep when you only contributed at an earlier stage of an example while the upvotes come for the later more substantial version is **wrong**. I can't stress these enough. This is gamification gone way out of line. In that spirit, why not award rep each time we login? Or when we turn off the ad-blocker? Or when we vote (as other sites do and has rendered their rep system practically meaningless)?

I believe that we keep trying too hard to assert each other that rep is just "worthless internet points". NO. When carefully curated, the Q&A rep system has merits that transcend SO's boundaries: From a purely professional standpoint, that gets translated into better job opportunities (regardless where you stand on the employer / employee spectrum), to the more personal gains an individual gets when trying to better oneself in the process of asking/answering questions. And the common denominator of these beneficial aspects is a permanent and rigorous quality assurance of the rep system itself.

### Breeding the new batch of rep-whores

Now, SO Central says that the Docs will eventually level-out and will not offer as much rep. This is like getting folks addicted to crack and then say "that's ok, in the future there will be limited supply of it". Once you addict people into getting massive amounts of rep (even with the rep cap on) for virtually no effort at all, then, when you finally 'level out', you will have created a new model army of rep whores (as if the existing one isn't big enough) rushing into more meaningless edit suggestions and answering even more crappy yet "popular" questions.

### The Quality per involvement ratio

Also, *Creating arrays in Java* doesn't exactly qualify as rocket science or the CS equivalent. It's not a bad example/post but still... The only reason I see it got so many upvotes is because there are people out there hunting badges (like `Backer`) and this example happens to be the first one in the most popular docs tag (which ofc is shown first). And I am really amazed that only 72 users edited that example given all it has to offer in terms of rep.

### Epilogue

I know that StackExchange/SO Central is a company. As such it *has* to employ techniques that help in establishing and maintaining a leading position in the respective market. But SO's success is only partially a result of successful marketing. Primarily (IMO), it is the result of the formation of a successful **community** of users around it. And rep is its currency. One would expect SO Central to be more careful when dealing with it. Is this the case here? (rhetorical question)

Comment: I can't help but think that documentation is a genius way to suck up the repwhores so they have less time to feed the help-vampire/repwhore cycle on SO.

Comment: Once the rep flow in docs tightens I fear they will return more hungry than ever...

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31917532#31917532

Comment: @Mysticial [Rincewind incarnated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rincewind)

Comment: @Mysticial Docs feels like [camp 5](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/3933332) (camp 5 = (camp 3)^2). I think you need to make a new diagram :]

Comment: @Rizier, -1, not enough elevens.

Comment: Well said! I like rep, but I also like the idea I deserved it. This SE Docs rep system feels like a slap in the face. Really, I feel personally offended to see given away for (almost) free now what took me five years of conscientiously answering questions. Of course this attracts rep whores like crazy. Worse, It deters users who like to write good documentation and see their work vandalized by others who seem to see their carefully composed example only as a free ride to more rep.

Comment: @Rizier123 camp 6 actually, since there already is a camp 5 in the comments

Comment: It just gets annoying when users misuse rep to censor others and even close questions they dont like after getting it cheaply

Comment: To be fair, I don't think that `Creating arrays in Java` has so many upvotes because of badge hunters - instead, it is likely to have those votes because it is helpful to the (very large) number of novice programmers.

Comment: Holy crap I had no idea it works this way! 8-O I am presuming SO is waiting to get the docs rolling, and then they will "fix the docs rep system" and punish them whores *and* actual contributors in a single step.

Comment: Do we have to prepare for rep inflation? Seems like there will be a Black Rep Friday. None of us would like to see unicorns jumping out from windows.

Comment: @Groo But some people actually deserve the rep, just maybe not from the upvotes

Comment: Upvotes should only change the order, not rep

Comment: Log in to SO, +5 (SE inbox, please dont fill up my cap)...buzz (from phone)...another **** notification (computer)...5 mins later...+5 (SE inbox, I JUST EMPTIED IT)...buzz (from phone)...another **** notification (really)...5 mins later...+5 (writing a userstyle to remove it from the SE toolbar)...buzz (my leg is gonna fall off)...another **** notification (turns on do not disturb)

Comment: "Hyperinflation is ended with drastic remedies, such as imposing the shock therapy of slashing government expenditures or altering the currency basis. ....Thus it is not surprising that there exist at least seven historical cases in which the good (foreign) money did fully drive out the use of the inflating currency. In the end the government had to legalize the former, for otherwise its revenues would have fallen to zero." from Wikipedia. What does that sound like to you?

Comment: @geek1011: that's exactly the problem, and that's why their statement about ["still adjusting the thresholds"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328703/addressing-documentation-repgateapocalypse) also sucks. Perhaps they should have posted their rep algorithm on code review before going live, because it's clear to most people reading this that the algorithm is ridiculously gameable.

Comment: @Groo Yes. Or at least they should have made doc worth nothing, then changed it after the first month, suprising everyone who contributed and not attracting rep whores

Comment: It's humorous to me that this is a problem to everyone now, but in the past on the q&a site, the restrictions on questions were much more lax and many more "easy" questions being asked to be answered, that still get upvotes to this day, since anything similar is closed as a duplicate, meaning it was much easier to get rep in the past.  People talk about "gamification" but demand that their SO rep function as a real life currency, or evaluation of their worth.  Please, get rid of all rep entirely, if only to stop the whining.

Comment: @everyone-else - Well yes, Java is indeed [popular](http://www.tiobe.com/tiobe_index), however [googling](https://www.google.gr/search?q=java+create+initialize+arrays) the topic still does not return the example, at least not at the first page. Plus the fact that this example had about 100+ upvotes from day 1 and still grows. I find it hard to believe that around 500 people discovered and upvoted this example based on their actual needs or its merits. Given the relatively short time that it's accessible online, it has attracted abnormaly high traffic.

Comment: @kik -You seem to be confused about what gamification is. The fact that it is strategically or tactically deployed in order to achieve mobilization via incentives does not necessarily mean that the outcome index (rep in our case) lacks any ties to "reality". On the contrary, when the index producing system is balanced and curated, it can "escape" its virtual origin and have actual impact in the "real" world. And (as is true with *every* currency) in the end, it means what we want it as a community to mean. Whether it is far from or close to reality is the issue that we are all discussing here.

Comment: [I hope that Google ignores popularity](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326696/839601) _'...Because if they wouldn't, my programming searches would probably be polluted with "wildly popular" (and useless) Reddit threads.'_

Comment: I wonder if it would be appropriate to start suggesting "Consider placing a bounty XXX for your question since answering it would require more than copy-paste kind of effort" where XXX would be in the range of 300-500 due to this recent inflation ;)

Comment: @Kik I agree, I think the reputation system was already broken. A little bit like a pink elephant making a mess in the backyard. Now, it is like it is making a mess inside the house i.e. harder to ignore. Statistics like 'accepted answers within 30 days / quarter / 1 year', (accepted answers / answers ratio, (questions with an accepted answer) / questions could have more meaning.

Answer (score 25):

I'd like to propose an alternative solution:

### Split the rep system.

The main problem here seems to be that Docs reputation is not "equivalent" to Q/A reputation, at least in terms of how hard it is to earn.  Thus, by making Docs rep separate from Q/A rep, we can maintain the gamification the reputation system provides and encourage people to contribute to Docs, without potentially "devaluing" people's hard-earned Q/A reputation.

Comment: This was formally proposed: [Reputation earned on Documentation should not unlock certain Stack Overflow privileges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328689), and while not tagged as "declined", the answer there says "no".

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of giving out +5 points to each contributor (and in this way bloating up the number of given rep points for each topic), the points should be *divided* between the contributors and not handed out additionally.
E.g. there are 5 contributors for one topic, then each contributor will get +1 reputation for an upvote. If there are 10 contributors, you'll get +.5.

Since broad topics with a lot of upvotes will most likely have most contributors, this system would make a lot of sense. It would be more 'valuable' to post a doc for a very particular topic that only one specialist knows about since there will likely be less contributors.

The only downside I see is that you end up with fractions of points. Instead of awarding them right away, I would combine them and only award full points when they are reached.
E.g. You will only be award 1 rep point when two users upvote a topic that you created with 9 other contributors.

Comment: [Documentation shares the work: make the rewards shared, not multiplicative](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329506)