# Who are the winners in the Documentation t-shirt drawing?

Tags: discussion, documentation, swag

The [Documentation launch blogpost](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/07/21/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/) mentioned that Stack Overflow's giving out 100 t-shirts through a draw to early contributors of Documentation.

> Oh, and since we really want to use this launch to expand the Stack Overflow Community tent, we’ve got some silly/shiny fun to encourage folks to jump right in!
>
> All users who contribute to Documentation the next four weeks:
>
> - Will get a silver “Documentation Pioneer” badge
> - Will be entered in a drawing to win one of 100 Stack Overflow T-Shirts

I didn't seem to see any posts on Meta regarding the winners. So, was this given out?

Comment: I'll ask around, but I don't recall ever doing that drawing. (I also didn't recall that the second bullet point existed.)

Comment: So, if I am reading this correctly, everyone who has the [Documentation Pioneer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6158/documentation-pioneer) is eligible to be in a drawing where 100 lucky users receive a shirt?

Comment: Shouldn't we fix Docs before making such a drawing?

Comment: @dorukayhan meh, I envision the t-shirt will be the titanic with an SO Docs logo ...

Comment: Right now, when it comes to Documentation, are there really any winners?

Comment: Oh, crap, I thought it was a contest to design T-Shirts with documentation on them, LOL. What about a T-shirt with the output of `man 1 find` printed on them :)

Comment: @j08691 Think of it this way: Exactly 100 people will benefit from SO Docs. :)

Comment: And here I thought it was "[100 lucky users will win 1600 rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329459/how-much-reputation-is-given-per-documentation-post-per-day-convert-to-communi)"